# ArrayList sort first by distance and then by type

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` that i am trying to sort based on two conditions. First by distance and then by type. `d_distance` is a double which is unique for each object. No two `d_distance` can be equal. `type` is an integer from `1-6` and two objects can be of same type. Here is my implementation:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Abc>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Abc lhs, Abc rhs) {

                if (lhs.d_distance > rhs.d_distance)
                    return 1;

                if (lhs.d_distance < rhs.d_distance){

                    if (lhs.type > rhs.type)
                        return 1;

                    if (lhs.type < rhs.type)
                        return -1;

                    return -1
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @barq My implementation is not working

Comment: That is not a question. Explain _exactly_ what isn't working. Wrong output? Exceptions? Errors?

Comment: @Takendarkk wrong output. It is not sorting properly

Answer (score 1):

Simplest implementation.

```
            @Override
            public int compare(Abc lhs, Abc rhs) {

                if (lhs.d_distance != rhs.d_distance)
                    return lhs.d_distance < rhs.d_distance ? -1 : 1;

                return lhs.type - rhs.type;
            }
```

But since you said the distances are never equal, it's pointless to sort by type as a secondary sort. Therefore:

```
            @Override
            public int compare(Abc lhs, Abc rhs) {
              return Double.compare(lhs.d_distance, rhs.d_distance);
            }
```

Comment: this will never call (lhs.type - rhs.type) since distances are never equal

Comment: Yup. Those were your requirements. If sort by distance first, and distances never equal, then not possible to sort by type at second level.

Answer (score 0):

Use the JDK utility methods [`Double.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,%20double)) and [`Integer.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) to help compare:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Abc>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Abc lhs, Abc rhs) {
            int c = Double.compare(lhs.d_distance, rhs.d_distance);
            return c == 0 ? Integer.compare(lhs.type, rhs.type) : c;
        }
    });
```

But if distances are truly unique, there's no value is coding for them being equal, so:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Abc>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Abc lhs, Abc rhs) {
            return Double.compare(lhs.d_distance, rhs.d_distance);
        }
    });
```